# out of memory in golang when parsing Freebase RDF

Tags: go, out-of-memory, freebase

I'm parsing through the triples of the Freebase RDF compressed and streaming with the XML package in Golang. However, I'm getting an out of memory error.

Do I have to garbage-collect? How can I do that? How can I clear the memory after I'm doing writing that triple to the XML file?

Here's my code: http://play.golang.org/p/dWvbtcs7wy

package main

```
import(
    "bufio"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
 )

 var inputFile = flag.String("infile", "freebase-rdf", "Input file path")
 var filter, _ = regexp.Compile("^file:.*|^talk:.*|^special:.*|^wikipedia:.*|^wiktionary:.*|^user:.*|^user_talk:.*")
type Redirect struct {
     Title string `xml:"title,attr"`
}

type Page struct {
    Title    string `xml:"title"`
    Abstract string `xml:""`
}

func CanonicaliseTitle(title string) string{
     can := strings.ToLower(title)
     can = strings.Replace(can, " ", "_", -1)
     can = url.QueryEscape(can)
     return can
 }

 func convertFreebaseId(uri string) string{
     if strings.HasPrefix(uri, "<") && strings.HasSuffix(uri, ">") {
        var id = uri[1 : len(uri)-1]
        id = strings.Replace(id, "http://rdf.freebase.com/ns", "", -1)
        id = strings.Replace(id, ".", "/", -1)
        return id
     }
     return uri
 }

 func parseTriple(line string) (string, string, string){
     var parts = strings.Split(line, "\t")
     subject := convertFreebaseId(parts[0])
     predicate := convertFreebaseId(parts[1])
     object := convertFreebaseId(parts[2])
     return subject, predicate, object
 }

 var (
     validRegexp = regexp.MustCompile("^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_-]*$")
     englishRegexp = regexp.MustCompile("@en")
 )

 func validTitle(content []string) bool{
     for _, v := range content{
         if !englishRegexp.MatchString(v) && len(v) > 1 && strings.Index(v, "[]") != -1{
         }  
     }
     return true
  }

 func validText(content []string) bool{
     for _, v := range content{
         if !validRegexp.MatchString(v) && len(v) > 1 && strings.Index(v, "[]") != -1{
             return false
         }
     }
     return true
 }

 func processTopic(id string, properties map[string][]string, file io.Writer){
     if validTitle(properties["/type/object/name"]) && validText(properties["/common/document/text"]){
         fmt.Fprintf(file, "<card>\n")
         fmt.Fprintf(file, "<title>\"%s\"</title>\n", properties["/type/object/name"])
         fmt.Fprintf(file, "<image>\"%s/%s\"</image>\n", "https://usercontent.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/image", id)
         fmt.Fprintf(file, "<text>\"%s\"</text>\n", properties["/common/document/text"])
         fmt.Fprintf(file, "<facts>\n")
         for k, v := range properties{
             for _, value := range v{
                  fmt.Fprintf(file, "<fact property=\"%s\">%s</fact>\n", k, value)
             }
         }
         fmt.Fprintf(file, "</facts>\n")
         fmt.Fprintf(file, "</card>\n")
     }
 }

 func main(){
     var current_mid = ""
     current_topic := make(map[string][]string)
     f, err := os.Open(*inputFile)
     if err != nil {
         fmt.Println(err)
         return
     }
     r := bufio.NewReader(f)
     xmlFile, _ := os.Create("freebase.xml")
     line, err := r.ReadString('\n')
     for err == nil{
         subject, predicate, object := parseTriple(line)
         if subject == current_mid{
             current_topic[predicate] = append(current_topic[predicate], object)
         }else if len(current_mid) > 0{
              processTopic(current_mid, current_topic, xmlFile)
              current_topic = make(map[string][]string)
         }
         current_mid = subject
         line, err = r.ReadString('\n')
     }
     processTopic(current_mid, current_topic, xmlFile)
     if err != io.EOF {
         fmt.Println(err)
         return
     }
 }
```

Comment: Did you check the size of your map when predicate is not unique? Because the only thing i can think off, is that when predicate already exists, it keeps adding object to it. This could mean that a record become very big.

Comment: Just throwing a bunch of code at us is not enough. We need a reproducible error. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is your problem, although reading your code it seems you're not leaking anything - but you can tune GC behavior a bit with `SetGCPercent()` http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#SetGCPercent

According to TFM, `a collection is triggered when the ratio of freshly allocated data to live data remaining after the previous collection reaches this percentage.`. The default rate is 100%, meaning for programs that make lots of small allocations and hold lots of RAM, the overhead can be huge. I had an HTTP cache take up over 200% the cache size once. Try tuning the percentage to somewhere around 10% and see if it helps.